# Ignore "where" clause in Laravel database query if no filter is provided

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

I'm currently trying to find the cleanest way to go about a query in Laravel 5.1. I'm creating an API that will return a JSON string from a MySQL database.

I would like to be able to have a URL like

```
mydomain.com/api/courses
```

which will return a JSON list of all of our courses. And I would also like to be able to pass in a GET query parameter like

```
mydomain.com/api/courses?subject=BUS
```

which will return only business courses. Pretty basic so far. In my controller, I have

```
$subject = \Request::input('subject');

if ($subject) {                                     //filter to only query parameters
    $results    = \DB::table('course_listings')
                    ->where('subject', $subject)
                    ->get();
} else {                                            //return all results
    $results = \DB::table('course_listings')->get();
}
```

However, it seems a little unnecessarily messy, especially if I want to start adding in additional query parameters. What I would like to do is to be able to just ignore the `where()` if the query parameter is blank.

```
$results = \DB::table('course_listings')
    ->where('subject', $subject) //ignore this line if no $subject
    ->get();
```

And for performance purposes, I would also want to avoid having to load all of the results, and then applying the filter afterwards. Is there anything in Laravel built for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can save your query to a variable, and then only apply the `where` in your `if` block:

```php
$subject = Request::input('subject');

$query = DB::table('course_listings');

if ($subject) {
    $query->where('subject', $subject);
}

$results = $query->get();
```

---

If you want to completely forgo the `if` statement, you can do this:

```php
$constraints = array_only(Request::input(), 'subject');

$results = DB::table('course_listings')->where($constraints)->get();
```

Comment: Ahh, perfect. And for each additional query parameter, I would just need an additional `if` statement, correct?

Comment: @cchapman - if you have many such parameters, maybe using `array_only` is better.